# Subscriptions are not showing in live app ios

Tags: javascript, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, react-native-iap

I have an React-Native iOS app which has renewable subscription configured by [react-native-iap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-iap). In the testing and testflight I can see the available subscription but after my app got approved and went live user can't see the subscription.

Apple has rejected the subscriptions for some modifications and I resubmit the subscription with new version of app with modifications and the subscription got approved but it is not showing in live app. I've been waiting more than 24hrs as a quick google search showed me that subscription will take time to get live but its been more than 24hrs and still no update.

The image of [subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg0sZ.png)
The image of [billing grace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAdxC.png)

I don't know that this billing grace period has server environment "Sandbox", does it cause this issue?